# Twilio recordingStatusCallback is never called

Tags: twilio, twilio-api, twilio-twiml

Trying to receive recordings of calls. I'm self hosting this twiml code.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<Response>
    <Dial timeout="40" 
         recordingStatusCallbackEvent="in-progress,completed"
         recordingStatusCallback="http://server.com/recording/">
        <Number 
             url="http://server.com/whisper/" 
             statusCallbackEvent="completed"
             statusCallback="http://server.com/status/">
             +12142142144
        </Number>
    </Dial>
</Response>
```

Everything works as expected except the recording url is never called. The call forwards, the whisper is spoken, the status url is called, but not the recording url.

Comment: I am also facing a similar problem, can someone please help: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65256973/twilio-recording-status-callback-event-is-not-called-when-recording-is-complete

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Twilio Developer Evangelist here.

It looks like you're missing the `record` attribute. (https://www.twilio.com/docs/voice/twiml/dial#record) If it's not set it's defaulting to `do-not-record`.

```
<Response>
    <Dial record="record-from-ringing-dual"
          recordingStatusCallback="www.myexample.com">
        <Number>+15558675310</Number>
    </Dial>
</Response>
```

Can you add it and give it a try? Happy to help if that's not the issue. :)