# Twilio recording_status_callback_event is not called when recording is complete

Tags: twilio, twilio-python

I am using Twilio to record calls using RecordVerb in Python. Here is how I am using it

```py
response.record(action='/exit/graceful?lang='+lang, timeout=5, play_beep='true',
                        recording_status_callback='/recording/callback?lang='+lang,
                        recording_status_callback_event='complete in-progress absent', finish_on_key='#')
```

But my recording_status_callback event is not getting triggered when the recording is complete. It is getting triggered during in-progress event but not when it is completed

Please help

Answer (score 0):

Twilio developer evangelist here.

The [event you are looking for is "completed"](https://www.twilio.com/docs/voice/twiml/record#attributes-recording-status-callback-event) not "complete". Try:

```py
response.record(action='/exit/graceful?lang='+lang, timeout=5, play_beep='true',
                        recording_status_callback='/recording/callback?lang='+lang,
                        recording_status_callback_event='completed in-progress absent', finish_on_key='#')
```